Forwarding Traffic Through Cloudflare Warp on Ubuntu Server with SSH Proxy
I have configured an SSH connection on my Ubuntu server and established an SSH proxy using Nekoray on both my Windows and Android devices. Currently, when I browse the internet through this setup, my server's IP address is exposed.
My goal is to utilize Cloudflare Warp on the server to mask my traffic and display Cloudflare's IP address when browsing the internet.
How can I integrate Cloudflare Warp with my existing SSH and Nekoray setup on the Ubuntu server?
